# Parsing html5 <time> datetime attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this element :

```
<time class="timeAgo" datetime="2011-07-30T13:00:00-03:00">1hour ago</time>
```

after ~1 minute i would like to update the string inside to like '1hour and 1 minute ago', so the problem is :
I cant parse the datetime attribute in internet explorer. And if i cant parse this datetime, i cant compare it to current time to make the time diff i want.

```
var testTime = new Date( $(".timeAgo").attr('datetime') );
```

the line above didnt work in IE8.

any ideas to workaround this ?

Comment: i'll just leave this here.... http://timeago.yarp.com/ it supports the html5 time tag too

Comment: Thats great mark, solves my problem. tnx

Comment: i'll make it an answer then. glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of coding this yourself, you can try the [timeago jquery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/).